# Minimize a function regarding two coupling variables

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Given known matrics $A\in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ and known vectors $b\in \mathbb R^2, c\in \mathbb R^2$, for the two optimization variables $x\in \mathbb R^2$ and $y\in \mathbb R$, how to obtain the optimal variables $x$ and $y$ by minimizing the following expression:
\begin{array}{rCl}
x, y &=& \underset{x\in \mathbb R^2, y\in \mathbb R}{\operatorname{argmin}} x^\top A x - 2b^\top x - 2yc^\top x + 2y^2 +2
\end{array}

Is there an explicit solution for the two variables $x,y$? If no, how to obtain the optimal $x,y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stationary conditions are

$$
\cases{
2A x-2b-2y c=0\\
-2c^Tx+2y=0
}
$$

and after substitution

$$
Ax-b-c^T x c=0
$$

developing we arrive at

$$
\cases{
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2-b_1-(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)c_1=0\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2-b_2-(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)c_2=0\\
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
(a_{11}-c_1^2)x_1+(a_{12}-c_1c_2)x_2-b_1=0\\
(a_{21}-c_1c_2)x_1+(a_{22}-c_2^2)x_2-b_2=0\\
}
$$

or

$$
\left(A-c c^T\right)x = b
$$

etc.